# JBPM 6.4 persistence unit on project

Tags: hibernate, persistence, jbpm

I created a new repository and a new Project in JBPM 6.4. Inside project I created a `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="demox:com.prueba:1.0" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>demox.com.prueba.Estudiante</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Also I defined a persistible object (pojo decorated with `@Entity`).

Now I have a simple process with only a one script task.

**But when I deployed the process in my DB the `Student` table is created...**

```java
package demox.com.prueba;

/**
 * This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool.
 */

@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Estudiante implements java.io.Serializable
{

   static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "ESTUDIANTE_ID_GENERATOR")
   @javax.persistence.Id
   @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "ESTUDIANTE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "ESTUDIANTE_ID_SEQ")
   private java.lang.Long id;

   @org.kie.api.definition.type.Label(value = "name")
   private java.lang.String name;

   public Estudiante()
   {
   }

   public java.lang.Long getId()
   {
      return this.id;
   }

   public void setId(java.lang.Long id)
   {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public java.lang.String getName()
   {
      return this.name;
   }

   public void setName(java.lang.String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public Estudiante(java.lang.Long id, java.lang.String name)
   {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
   }

}
```

**So the question is: how get inside this `scriptTask` the reference to this `EntityManger` to persist this pojo?**

I tried:

```java
demox.com.prueba.Estudiante est=new demox.com.prueba.Estudiante();
String pu="demox:com.prueba:1.0";

//javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( pu );

javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory emf = (javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory) kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().getEnvironment()
                            .get(org.kie.api.runtime.EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY); # tried also EnvironmentName.CMD_SCOPED_ENTITY_MANAGER

System.out.println("Entity manager " + emf );

emf.persist(est);
```

But when used this code the EntityManager is a reference to a JBPM persistence unit not a instance to my persistence unit(demo) which don't contain my pojo class (unknown Entity).

So how can acces to this persistence unit in my script task?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to do such complex operations as database calls in [script tasks](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch06.html#d0e3430). You should use a [service task](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch06.html#d0e3485) instead with your own implementation of [work item handler](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch21.html#sec.workitemhandler.overview). There is already a custom [JPAWorkItemHandler](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-workitems/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/jpa/JPAWorkItemHandler.java) implementation which you can probably use.